# Regex parse Buffy Script using look behinds

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a difficult time parsing this page: http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/transcripts/114_tran.html

I'm attempting to get the character name with the associated dialogue.
The text looks like this:

```
<p>BUFFY: Wait!
<p>She stands there panting, watching the truck turn a corner.
<p>BUFFY: (whining) Don't you want your garbage?
<p>She sighs, pouts, turns and walks back toward the house.
<p>Cut to the kitchen. Buffy enters through the back door, holding a pile of
mail. She begins looking through it. We see Dawn standing by the island.
<p>DAWN: Hey Buffy. Oh, don't forget, today's trash day.<br>BUFFY: (sourly)
Thanks.
<p>Dawn piles her books into her school bag. Buffy opens a letter.
<p>Close shot of the letter.
<p>
<p>Dawn smiles, and she and Willow exit. Buffy picks up the still-wrapped
sandwich and stares at it.
<p>BUFFY: (to herself) Somebody should.
<p>She sighs, puts the sandwich back in the bag.
<p>Cut to the Bronze. Pan across various people drinking and dancing,
bartender serving. Reveal Xander and Anya sitting at the bar eating chips from
several bags. A notebook sits in front of them bearing the wedding seating
chart.
<p>ANYA: See ... this seating chart makes no sense. We have to do it again.
(Xander nodding) We can't do it again. You do it.<br>XANDER: The seating
chart's fine. Let's get back to the table arrangements. I'm starting to have
dreams of gardenia bouquets. (winces) I am so glad my manly coworkers didn't
just hear me say that. (eating chips)
```

Ideally, I'd match from `<p>` or `<br>` to the next `<p>` or `<br>`. I was trying to use look aheads and look behinds for this:

```
reg = "((?<=<p>)|(?<=<br>))(?P<character>.+):(?P<dialogue>.+)((?=<p>)|(?=<br>))"
script = re.findall(reg, html_text)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't match anything. When I leave off the lookahead `((?=<p>)|(?=<br>))`, I match lines as long as there isn't a newline in the matching dialogue. It seems to terminate at the newline instead of continuing to the `<p>`

ex. On this line, the "Thanks" isn't matched.  `<p>DAWN: Hey Buffy. Oh, don't forget, today's trash day.<br>BUFFY: (sourly)
  Thanks.`

Thank you for any insight you have!

Comment: Which python? For me the first version matches something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around the dot notation:

```
re.findall('((?<=<p>)|(?<=<br>))([A-Z]+):([^<]+)', text)
```

Also you can try a [special flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to include linebreaks into the semantics of the dot. Personally, when I can I use splits or some html parser. RE escaping, all the parameters, limitations and flags can drive mad anyone. There is also re.split.

```
dialogs = {}
text = html_text.replace('<br>', '<p>')
paragraphs = text.split('<p>')

for p in paragraphs:
    if ":" in p:
        char, line = p.split(":", 1)
        if char in dialogs:
           dialogs[char].append(line)
        else:
           dialogs[char] = []
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!